# While loop refusing to work

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, mysqli, while-loop

I did make a post previously but was not able to properly explain my issue nor was I able to get it resolved. This is what I have.

```
$shoutlines = file($shout_file);

$aTemp = array();
foreach($matches['user'] as $user) {
    $aTemp[] = "'" . $user . "'";
}
$user = implode(",", $aTemp);

$rara = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username IN ( $user )"; // Tried this statment both as a query and prepared statement
$getlevel = $db->query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username IN '( ".$user." )'"); // Tried this both as a query and prepared statement
//$getlevel->bind_param('s', $user);
//$getlevel->execute();
//$level = $getlevel->get_result();
//$getlevel->store_result();
while($getdb = $getlevel->fetch_assoc()){
    //output the html
        for($i = 0; $i < (1000); $i++)
        {
            if(isset($shoutlines[$i]))
            {

                $shoutline = preg_replace('/<\/div>\n/', ' ', $shoutlines[$i], 1);
                echo showSmileys($shoutline) . "<div class='delete'><a href='javascript: delete_shoutline({$i});' title='Delele'>delete</a></div></div>";
            }
        }
}
```

I have a `for` loop within the `while` loop that will not run within it, if I move the `for` loop outside of the `while` it works fine, but I need it in the `while` loop to make checks of the users for post titles, abilities etc., that are saved in my database. I have shown what I have tried so far when to comes to identifying the problem, I have tried dieing out errors if the query, binds, or executes weren't showing true, but got now hits. The code for this is pulled out so there isn't too much clutter for your reading abilities, any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try to echo that "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = '".$user."'", I think it will look wrong

Comment: Looks like this, unless my eyes have gone crazy from looking at this code all day it looks fine `SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = 'kira423,testin,kira423,kira423,kira423,kira423,kira423,kira423,kira423,kira423,kira423,kira423,kira423,kira423,kira423,kira423'` I know it repeats but it is checking from a text file for the information and this is the only way I know to go about it.

Comment: you should use `OR` or `AND`, http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp

Comment: Thats going to be a huge query dont you think? It doesn't delete posts until the file reaches 100 lines, so that would mean a query with 99 `OR`'s in it. I did go out on a limb and try it out that way, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: What is type of your `username`? Is it varchar/string?

Comment: @SubRed it's a string, does that have something to do with it?

Comment: Just to be sure, you know that a row with `username='kira423'` would not be matched with your query (`WHERE username='kira423,kira424,kira425'`), right?

Comment: Yes, it does. Like in `IN` you should use `username IN ('kira1','kira2','kira3')`.

Comment: `$rara = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username IN ( $user )";` what's wrong with that query?

Comment: @JonathandeM. Because that would look like `WHERE username IN (kira423,kira424,kira425)`, **not** `WHERE username IN ('kira432','kira424','kira425')`.

Comment: I'm not sure what database library that is, but you really, really should see if it supports [prepared statements with parameterized queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).  It will save you quite a bit of heartache and help mitigate the [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack you're currently open to.

Comment: @Charles I am using prepared statements, please read the full OP I have tried both prepared statements and non prepared statements, and I am currently using XAMPP to test, and I know that my host supports them.

Comment: @kira423, you might be using prepared statements, but you are *not* using parameterized queries.  You're concatenating user input *directly* into SQL.  This is highly insecure.  Please, please read the linked wikipedia articles.

Comment: @Charles please take a look at the commented out code and you will see that I was using paramerterized queries, I have it different atm to test if it was the issue in my code. I know how to use them, I am not an idiot, and please do not question my debugging methods, we all do it different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When "exploding" the username, you need ot wrap each username in quotes, not the whole thing. Also make the names safe for data entry.

```
$aTemp = array();
foreach($matches['user'] as $user) {
    $aTemp[] = '"' . mysql_real_escape_string($user) . '"';
}
$user = implode(",", $aTemp);
```

Then use the first query:

```
"SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username IN ( $user )";
```

---

Edit: adding error checking:

```
$getlevel = $db->query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username IN ( $user )");
if ($getlevel == false) {
    // Normally you'll build into a function or class, but this is the simple example
    // Never output SQL errors on a live site, but log to file or (if you can do it safely) the database.
    echo 'Whoopsie<br />';
    var_dump($db->errorInfo());
    exit();
}
```

Comment: With this I am getting `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\gptcode\shoutbox\update.php on line 116`

Line 116 is `while($getdb = $getlevel->fetch_assoc()){`

Comment: In which case there is an SQL error, the "query" is returning false. You should always see if result is false, and if so, echo/report the error. I can't see a problem with the code above, so can you tell me what error the SQL is reporting and we can go from there?

Comment: It does return any error I added in `printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $getlevel->error);` it just puts Errormessage: but nothing after it. Also tried what you put above, and nothing.

Comment: There's some typo then (either in your or mine). Next stage, when debugging, always have full error reporting enabled. Add the following just above: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'on');` and it'll tell you if there are some undeclared variables or typos etc. If that doesn't help - can you add an edit to your question with the latest code you have?

Comment: I have updated my OP because error reporting is showing nothing.

Comment: Never mind i fixed it, it was a typo on my end, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Using data binding with `IN` clauses is not that nice, so if you really need `IN` and don't care about using the old, deprecated `mysql_*` function, try this:

```
$user="'".implode("','",array_map(function($s){
  return mysql_real_escape_string($s);
},$matches["user"])."'";
$rara="SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username IN ($user)";
```